# Create a Java File object (or equivalent) using a byte array in memory (without a physical file)

Tags: java, spring, file, memory, io

I want to create a Java `File` object in memory (without creating a physical file) and populate its content with a byte array.

Can this be done?

The idea is to pass it to a Spring `InputStreamSource`. I'm trying the method below, but it returns saying "the byte array does not contain a file name.".

```
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);      
helper.setFrom("no-reply@example.com", "xyz");
helper.setTo(email);
helper.setText(body,true);
helper.setSubject(subject);
helper.addInline("cImage",
        new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArr)));

mailSender.send(message);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you paste the full stack trace?  There is no such thing as an "in memory" file.  Using a ByteArrayInputStream should be sufficient.

---

You need to implement Resource#getFilename().  Try the following:

```
helper.addInline("cImage", new ByteArrayResource(imageByteArr){
            @Override
            public String getFilename() {
                return fileName;
            }
        });
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: resource loaded from byte array does not carry a filename
        at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource.getFilename(AbstractResource.java:148)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.addInline(MimeMessageHelper.java:922)

Comment: You can hopefully see it in action soon at www.creately.com :) (We are in private beta atm.)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need to use the [other constructor of InputStreamResource](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html#InputStreamResource(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String))?

Comment: Nope. I get - 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: abc.png does not carry a filename
        at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource.getFilename(AbstractResource.java:148)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.addInline(MimeMessageHelper.java:922)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the resource you feed to addInline()? If you wanted the resource to be in memory, I would have tried a org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource.

Update:
I think you might need to use the DataSource version of the addInline() method and then use a byte array bound data source object to feed the data into the helper class. I would try the following:

```
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);              
helper.setFrom("no-reply@example.com", "xyz");
helper.setTo(email);
helper.setText(body,true);
helper.setSubject(subject);

// use javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource
ByteArrayDataSource imgDS = new ByteArrayDataSource( imageByteArr, "image/png");
helper.addInline("cImage", imgDS);

mailSender.send(message);
```

Comment: Tried it. Same exception :( 

What I get is a raw array of bitmap data. Looks like I need to put it into a file before anything?

Comment: You might need to use the version of addInLine() that accepts a DataSource as your second parameter. There is a javax.util.mail.ByteArrayDataSource that implements the functionality of wrapping a byte array without a physical file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its worth trying a different overload of the method:

```
addInline(String contentId, 
          InputStreamSource inputStreamSource, 
          String contentType)
```

I.e.:

```
addInline("cImage", 
          new InputStreamSource () 
          {  
             final private InputStream src = 
                                     new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArr);
             public InputStream getInputStream() {return src;}
          },
          "image/jpeg"); // or whatever image type you use
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to create the  MimeMessageHelper object correctly to support attachments and inline resources.

Example: MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");

In this example since multipart is set to true  MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED will be used and attachments and inline resouces will be supported.