# Specifying the filename while creating a File Object it from byte array (without creating a physical file)

Tags: java, file-io, jakarta-mail

I was stuck to a problem exactly same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578305/create-a-java-file-object-or-equivalent-using-a-byte-array-in-memory-without/15023104#15023104)
and with the solution posted i was able to solve my issue.
But now the problem is, when the attachment is received, there is no name for it. In my method, i have asked for receiver's email id, subject , content, filename and byte[] for the File. There is no problem in format of the file i am passing but problem is with the name. The recipient gets "noname" as file name. How do we specify the filename of our choice. The filename which i am passing as parameter doesnt gets reflected. Please suggest.

The code which i am using is

```
File file = new File("D:/my docs/Jetty.pdf");
int len1 = (int)(file.length());
FileInputStream fis1 = null;
try {
    fis1 = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
byte buf1[] = new byte[len1];
try {
    fis1.read(buf1);
    EmailServiceClient.sendEmailWithAttachment("xyz@gmail.com", "abc@gmail.com", "Hi", "PFA", "Jetty.pdf", buf1);

    System.out.println("SENT");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My email service Implementation for this goes here

```
public void sendEmailWithAttachment(String emailIdTo, String emailIdFrom, String subject, String content,
    final String fileName, byte[] file) {
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
try {
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
    helper.setTo(emailIdTo);
    helper.setFrom(emailIdFrom);
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    helper.setText(content, true);
    helper.addInline("attachment", new ByteArrayResource(file) {
        @Override
        public String getFilename() {
            return fileName;
        }
    });
    mailSender.send(message);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    throw new MailParseException(e);
}}
```

Please someone help in figuring this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Spring Documentation I can say that the inlined elements don't have special names besides the contentId. Maybe you want to add an attachment instead using the addAttachment method? Then you can have a name for your file.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply @toomasr but my previous problem was the link which i have referred. My problem was to add attachments in the email without creating physical file and the solution there did the trick. but now the email attachment received does not have any name and I dnt know how to fix that.